# How can I encrypt and decrypt passwords in a Perl CGI program?

Tags: perl, cgi

Am new to Perl CGI, using ActivePerl, SQLite DB, Apache server and Windows. 
I have an entry form in which their are fields like Id, Name, Password and so
on. Whenever anybody makes a new entry then whatever they enter into password 
field that should be encrypted and get stored in database.

The next time when that same user enters the password then it should be validated. Now
I suppose a decrypt function or code is required.

I found something called MD5 encryption. Please can anybody give 
me more info about this and help me regarding how to write the code or any link
regarding this?

Comment: Based on your question, you should not try to do this yourself. Find an authentication framework.

Comment: I recommend [`Authen::Passphrase`](http://p3rl.org/Authen::Passphrase) with Eksblowfish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call `make_crypto_hash` when you initially set up the user, the parameter is his given passphrase. Store the function return value in the database.

```
sub make_crypto_hash {
    my ($passphrase) = @_;
    return Authen::Passphrase::BlowfishCrypt->new(
        cost        => 8,
        salt_random => 1,
        passphrase  => $passphrase,
    )->as_rfc2307;
}
```

Call `match_passphrase_against_crypto_hash` when someone logs in and you want to see whether the passphrase belongs to the user. The parameters are the crypto hash you retrieve from the database for the given user name, and the passphrase just given by the user. The return value is boolean.

```
sub match_passphrase_against_crypto_hash {
    my ($crypto_hash, $passphrase) = @_;
    return Authen::Passphrase::BlowfishCrypt
        ->from_rfc2307($crypto_hash)->match($passphrase);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot for the code i gona use this in my Program and get back to you if i get struck anywhere...Thank You once again Mr.Daxim..

Comment: @jene: if this answer works for you, it is proper etiquette to mark it as accepted (click the outlined checkmark next to this question).

Comment: this level of perfection and completeness in a stackoverflow answer are possible ONLY in Perl ...

Answer (score 0):

MD5 converts any string into a digest.
To check if the user's password is valid you don't need the password from the database, but only compare the digest from their entered one to the digest you stored.

Comment: MD5 is a hash, albeit an obsolete one, so it does not "encrypt" anything.

Comment: By the way MD5 encryption is not reversible, that is you cann't restore original password.

Comment: It's not encryption, it's a hashing algorithm. Please get the terminology right, these are different concepts of cryptography.

Comment: Hey Thanks alot for all these Important Informations..But what do i do now? should i go browse for md5 encryption code or opt for anyother available..?

Comment: @Ljubomir: You can if you have a rainbow table for an unsalted hash, which is just one more reason why I recommend that jene reuse an existing authentication framework before reinventing the wheel with an octagon.

Comment: @jene: MD5 is not encryption. Go look for an authentication framework that is appropriate for your platform.

Comment: This answer is terribly bad. It recommends an outdated weak hashing algorithm, and does not mention salting at all.

Comment: I wouldn't say this answer "recommends" the use of MD5, it just fails to discourage it. The question's final paragraph asks what MD5 is and how it's used for password handling and Ljubomir has answered that; he did not introduce MD5 to the discussion.