# Password encryption and storing of password - Perl

Tags: perl, encryption

We have some scripts which uses password to login to a system. These passwords are stored in ini file and are consumed by the scripts (Perl).

I was thinking of storing the password encrypted (not sure which package to use for now) and decrypt the same in the Perl code.

But logically it doesn't makes sense to store the password encrypted and the decrypt logic in code.

These files are in source control and can be accessed by most of the users.

Wondering what could be the better way.

I use Perl and any suggestions regarding which module I could use is welcomed :-)

Thanks

Karthik

P.S. The Perl file is a scheduled script running in server and is stored in source control tool. User has no interaction to these scripts except that these can be  viewed when someone access the soruce control.

Comment: It's not clear from the question if you need plain text passwords after reading ini file or not. If you need passwords then there are not many reasons in encrypting them. Your program should decrypt them somehow and probably people have access to the code, so people would be able to decrypt passwords if they need. Clarify your question.

Answer (score 4):

This, in fact, has little to do with Perl. You will mostly work with shell and filesystem.

If you need a password to access a remote service, you have to store it. Whether encrypted or not, they must be placed somewhere, probably on disk, especially when not run from within user session (e.g. GNOME).

It is a very bad idea to store passwords in public VCS. You should keep your code there only and store passwords in a separate file, out of VCS dirs. For example, if you have a copy of repo in `/opt/some-project/scripts`, put password file next to it, in `/opt/some-project/passwd`.

The most important issue is the file permissions of `passwd` file. Make it accessible only for the owner, root being the best one.

Then, run such a script in your root's crontab:

```
cat /opt/some-project/passwd | sudo -U <user> perl /opt/some-project/run-with-passwd-on-stdin
```

where `<user>` is the user (not root!) you wish to run your script as, and the script receives the password file as the standard input.

This way, the password file is protected as long as file permissions are correct and the root account is not compromised.

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't be decrypting passwords at all. You should store md5 sum of a password, then when user wants to log in, you calculate the md5 sum of what he typed in as a password and compare it with what you have in your files.

Of course there are other methods then md5, that is only an example. You can use SHA or any other one way hashing method.

Using this method makes you unable to restore forgotten password, you have to generate a new one to replace forgotten one.

I don't know Perl but I bet that there are available implementations of md5 or SHA1.

Comment: Actually these are scheduled scripts in Perl with no user interaction.

Comment: @KarthikKrishnan: It doesn't make a difference. Maciek's described strategy is still valid. There's no reason why you'd have to decrypt crypted passwords anyway. If you do, why bother crypting them in the first place?

Comment: Perl has an implementation of the C function `crypt` as a built-in and `Digest::MD5` and `Digest::SHA` are core modules.

Comment: Please don't cobble together your own authentication scheme on top of the software Maciek and flesk mentioned. See http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/. [Use bcrypt instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3676402)!

Comment: @flesk One reason to encrypt your passwords is that it would be (slightly) more difficult to get the plaintext ones. There are scenarios where this make sense. For example, if the database gets copied with an sql injection, encrypted passwords would be better than plaintext.

Comment: @Maciek, The OP can't use a hashing algorithm. He's trying to save a password that will be sent to a 3rd party, so it needs to be recoverable.