# How to get back my Laravel Hashed Password?

Tags: php, laravel, hash, passwords

I already saved my **Password** as hashed password in database and how to get password in original format?

My Password is:

```
 $2y$10$WASUjz4XeyjusUI5M7PY3.6vUNOofzMUiVEH/7agw6Gf4JQCWVwiy
```

Comment: You can't hashing is one way mechanism.

Comment: ... that's kind of the point of the hash. If someone gets a hold of your database, they're not supposed to be able to get back your password through your hash.

Comment: You dont get it back. But it may be possible to overwrite it with the hash of a new password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decrypt hash stored by bcrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084595/how-to-decrypt-hash-stored-by-bcrypt)

Comment: You can't deHash it you can check but you cannot view it's original strings. Laravel Security

Answer (score 10):

You cannot decrypt laravel password hash which is bcrypt. You can change it with new password.

And apply comparisons like this

**Edit**

You can get the hashedPassword like this:

```
$hashedPassword = Auth::user()->getAuthPassword();
```

And check like this:

```
if (Hash::check('password', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Comment: This is not useful because Karthik is asking for way to convert hashed password to its original form.

Comment: It does answer the question though. You can't.